# Unable to calculate with Optional Variables

Tags: swift

I have a simple App with 2 text fields
User just needs to enter Year of Service and Salary
I just need to multiply them.
Would like to output to a text label

(1) I have checked for a nil, and code passes
(2) but I am unable to convert the value to Int for multiplication
(3) debugged section by merely multiplying the Int(UserInputVariable.txt) * any number
(4) and just print. No output to debugging screen

```
 if let var1 = Int(staffYrOfServiceTextField.text!) {   
      let mult = var1 * 3
      print(mult)                            
 }
```

I expected output to debugging screen

Comment: What is the value you've entered in staffYrOfServiceTextField textfield?

Comment: When you say "I have checked for nil," what value have you checked for nil and how? I strongly suspect that `Int(staffYrOfServiceTextField.text!)` is returning nil here. What do you believe it's returning (how did you verify this)?

Comment: Why not add a print  of the text field before the `if`?

Answer (score 0):

You never "verify" that var1 is not nil in the output debugger.

```
 if let var1 = Int(staffYrOfServiceTextField.text!) {   
      let mult = var1 * 3
      print(mult)                            
 } else {
    // If reach here, then Int(staffYrOfServiceTextField.text!) is nil.
    print(staffYrOfServiceTextField.text)
    print("staffYrOfServiceTextField text does not conform to int or is nil")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem statement, there could be two ways to solve this:

1) When you have the textField's keyboard type only numeric, where you are sure about the input will definitely be integer only.

```
if let salary = txtFld_Salary.text, let exp = txtFld_YearOfExperience.text {
            let multi = Int(salary)! * Int(exp)!
            print(multi)
        }
```

2) If you havn't defined the keyboard type and user may enter string values in those then use below code to get the multiplication:

```
        if let salary = txtFld_Salary.text, let exp = txtFld_YearOfExperience.text {
            if let intSalary = Int(salary), let intExp = Int(exp) {
                let multi = intSalary * intExp
                print(multi)
            }
        }
```